# Add Percentage to Grouping Variable in gtsummary Package

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, gtsummary

I am in the process of creating gtsummary table based on the mortality status (the variable "fate") of the Bernard data included in the pubh package.

The issue I am facing is that I want to add the percentage of "Dead" and "Alive" next to their count.
But since this is the grouping variable, I haven't been able to configure it

This is my sample code for the table:

```
library(pubh)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

data("Bernard")


na.omit(Bernard)  %>% select(fate, race, apache) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = fate,
              
     type =  list(race ~ "categorical", apache ~ "continuous"),
     statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{min}, {max}", all_categorical() ~ "{p}%"),
     digits = list(all_continuous() ~ 2, all_categorical() ~ 2),
     missing_text = "(Missing)" ) %>% 
                
     add_stat_label() %>%
     modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
     modify_caption("**Table 1. Summary statistics by  Mortality Status**") %>%
     modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Fate**") %>%
     bold_labels() %>%
     italicize_labels() %>%
     italicize_levels()
```

[And this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFNnG.png)

Ideally, I  would like to have the table show : Alive, N = 96 **(67..%)**  Dead, N = 47 **(32..%)**

I have tried listing the "fate" variable as categorical and then providing the statistic for percentage:

```
               type =  list(c(race, **fate**) ~ "categorical", apache ~ "continuous"),
               
               statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{min}, {max}", all_categorical() ~ "{p}%", **fate ~ "{p}%"**),
```

This did not work

And I was also thinking that using mutate to create a new variable before using tbl_summary() would probably work, but I am curious if this can be configured explicitly within tbl_summary()

One could generalize the question to: whether summary statistics other than the number of observations can be shown for the grouping variable in gtsummary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the percentage to the header using the `modify_header()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.3'

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    include = age
  ) %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, N={n} ({style_percent(p)}%)") %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N=98 (49%) | **Drug B**, N=102 (51%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |
| Unknown | 7 | 4 |

<sup>Created on 2022-12-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! By repalcing modify_header of the above code with:                
modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**" , all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, N={n} ({style_percent(p)}%)") %>% ...           it worked.          Can I add decimals to it?

Comment: Yes, check out the arguments in `style_percent()` to round to more decimal places.

Comment: Thank you! Your website and answer to this question have been of great help to me and many others I think ; Merry Christmas! https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/style_pvalue.html